# Kavosh uses a different switching process in its MCMC; how concerned should I be?

Tags: algorithms, markov-chain-montecarlo, networks, graph-theory

[Kavosh](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/10/318) is a recent package designed for [network motif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_motif) discovery.  To give a comparison, Kavosh generates a collection of similar networks using an MCMC process.

The networks in consideration are directed graphs without loops or multiple edges.  *Similar* networks have the same vertex set and the same in-degrees and out-degrees.  Ideally we want to sample uniformly at random from the set of similar graphs.

As I understand it, network motif detection programs typically use a well-studied switching process:  take two directed edges (a,c) and (b,d) uniformly at random, then replace with (a,d) and (b,c).  Reject if a loop or multiple edge is formed.  (see e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0312028)

Judging from its source code, Kavosh seems to speed-up this process in the following way.  For all vertices v do:

- Let a=v.
- b is a random vertex b<>a.
- c is a random out-neighbour of a.
- d is a random out-neighbour of c.

And as before, replace edges (a,c) and (b,d) with (a,d) and (b,c).  Reject if a loop or multiple edge is formed.  Repeat this whole process three times (so there can be up to 3|V| switches applied in total, where |V| is the number of vertices).  [For some reason I'm unsure of, the last two steps are also repeated up to three times.]

> **Question**: What effects could one expect to see as a result of this change?  How concerned should one be about this change?

The Kavosh paper does not say much about it:

> In our approach, similar to Milo's
>   random model [17,18] switching
>   operations are applied on the edges of
>   the input network repeatedly, until
>   the network is well randomized.